# Evolution can get the mail list from server, but the content can't be loaded

Tags: evolution

I'm using Evolution to connect exchange server.

It can refresh the mail list from server, get the subject of new mail. However it can't show the content of those new mail in preview when I chose the subject.

I have kill the backend services of Evolution, then restart it. And it doesn't report any error after restarting.

Maybe it's caused by the disk is out of space where I store my mail. Now the folder has enough quota, how to let evolution to redownload those mail from server?

Comment: I have had similar problems with evolution and exchange, it use to be that evolution worked real nice with exchange, not so much any more, hopefully it is just a rough patch that the developers are going through, and they will get it sorted out in the near future...

Comment: @Thex, I agree with you. Evoulution is better than thurdbird in accessing exchange server. However the performance of accessing exchange server also has greate buffer to be improved. :)

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.